# NSManagedObject delete not working, can still retrieve the object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to delete a managed object, is there something I am missing?

```
[managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];

NSError *error;

if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    return NO;
}

return YES;
```

When I run this code the object can still be retrieved.

```
NSManagedObject *objectiveManagedObject = [managedObjectContext objectWithID:objectID];

return (ObjectiveManagedObject *)objectiveManagedObject;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context was not being saved properly

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do

```
[[self managedObjectContext] setPropagatesDeletesAtEndOfEvent:NO]
```

first?

Comment: this causes other code to break which clears the database between unit tests

Answer (score 0):

I note that you've switched between `self.managedObjectContext` and `managedObjectContext`. Are you certain these are the same variable? Avoid accessing your ivars directly; use accessors (except in `init` and `dealloc`). This avoids all kinds of problems.

Are you certain that `managedObject` has the ID `objectID`? They could be two objects that simply appear similar.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the previous answers didn't check out, I would say the most likely explanation is that the managed object is the last object in a required relationship. As such, it cannot be deleted until the object on the other end of the relationship is deleted or a second object is added to the relationship.

You might also want to check that the persistent store isn't set to readonly. I don't remember what errors you get when you try to write a readonly store.

Also, you might want to wait a few seconds before testing for the object. Saves are disk operation and therefore relatively slow. It is possible that the save actually fails.

You should be trapping the error return from the save in any case.